# How to fix a container at a particular spot on the screen

Tags: flutter

I'm learning flutter and I have made an app that looks like this:

[image]

I'm facing a problem as to how to fix the container fixed on a particular spot on the screen like it has to be aligned to the top center. Here's the problem I'm facing:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
class Program7 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Program7({super.key});

  @override
  State<Program7> createState() => _Program7State();
}

class _Program7State extends State<Program7> {
  double cHeightAndWidth = 300;

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: cHeightAndWidth,
            width: cHeightAndWidth,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              //A bunch of rows of buttons,
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

P.S.: I already tried to fix the container to the top center of another container using align but the purple color somehow bleeds out into the bigger container.

Comment: what is the parent of this widget

Comment: @YeasinSheikh material app -> scaffold -> safe area (this widget)

Comment: try my post on answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is using `MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,`. It will use the free space and put half before and another half at end of the child.

You can use fixed gap for top(Container).

```dart
return SafeArea(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(height: 50),
      Container(
        height: cHeightAndWidth,
        width: cHeightAndWidth,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.purple,
        ),
      ),
      Spacer(), // or other widget
      Column(
        children: [
          //A bunch of rows of buttons,
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: It works! But it will only work with a spacer so the rows of buttons got pushed towards the very bottom. I solved the issue by wrapping all the rows in a column and that column in a container with bottom margin.